# Async/Await deadlock

Tags: c#, async-await, deadlock

I can't seem to get my code work, although I tried several different approaches. Here is my preferred code snippet:

```
var client = await ApiClientProvider.GetApiClient();

        var freeToPlayChampions = await client.GetChampionsAsync(true, Region);

        var championsData = freeToPlayChampions.Select(x =>
            client.GetStaticChampionByIdAsync(
                (int)x.Id,
                platformId: Region));

        ConsoleTable.From(await Task.WhenAll(championsData)).Write();
```

When debugging I see that the code hangs on `await Task.WhenAll(championsData)`. So i tried to make the code more easy:

```
 var client = await ApiClientProvider.GetApiClient();

        var freeToPlayChampions = await client.GetChampionsAsync(true, Region);

        var table = new ConsoleTable();
        foreach(var freeToPlayChampion in freeToPlayChampions)
        {
            var championsData = client.GetStaticChampionByIdAsync(
                (int)freeToPlayChampion.Id,
                platformId: Region);

            table.AddRow(await championsData);
        }

        table.Write();
```

Unfortunately this hangs, as well. Again on the same code part, e.g. `await championsData`.

How can this 'easy' usage of async/await lead to an deadlock? Thanks in advance for help!

EDIT:

Here is the whole class:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConsoleTables;
using Mono.Options;
using RiotNet.Models;
using RiotShell.Properties;

namespace RiotShell
{
    public class FreeToPlay : IShellCommand
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Names { get; }
        public OptionSet Options { get; }

        public bool ShowHelp { get; private set; }
        public string Region { get; private set; }

        public FreeToPlay()
        {
            Names = new List<string>
            {
                "freetoplay",
                "ftp"
            };

            Options = new OptionSet
            {
                { "r|region=" , "The region to execute against", x => Region = x},
                { "h|help|?" , "Show help", x => ShowHelp = true }
            };
        }

        public async Task Execute(IEnumerable<string> args)
        {
            if (ShowHelp)
            {
                Options.WriteOptionDescriptions(Console.Out);
                return;
            }

            if (args.Any())
            {
                throw new Exception(Resources.TooManyArgumentsProvided);
            }

            if (Region == null)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format(Resources.RequiredOptionNotFound, "region"));
            }

            if (!PlatformId.All.Contains(Region))
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format(Resources.InvalidRegion, Region));
            }

            var client = await ApiClientProvider.GetApiClient();

            var freeToPlayChampions = await client.GetChampionsAsync(true, Region);

            var championsData = freeToPlayChampions.Select(x =>
            client.GetStaticChampionByIdAsync(
                (int)x.Id,
                platformId: Region));

            ConsoleTable.From(await Task.WhenAll(championsData)).Write();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the caller code, my main method:

```
    using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RiotShell.Properties;

namespace RiotShell
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write(Resources.RiotShellLineString);
                var input = Console.ReadLine();

                try
                {
                    var parsedArgs = InputParser.Parse(input);

                    (var command, var commandArgs) = ArgsToIShellCommandCaster.GetCommand(parsedArgs);

                    await command.Execute(commandArgs);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since it was wished, here the code for the ApiProvider:

```
using RiotNet;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RiotShell
{
    public class ApiClientProvider
    {
        private static IRiotClient _client;

        public static async Task<IRiotClient> GetApiClient()
        {
            if (_client != null)
            {
                _client.Settings.ApiKey = await KeyService.GetKey();
                return _client;
            }

            _client = new RiotClient(new RiotClientSettings
            {
                ApiKey = await KeyService.GetKey()
            });

            return _client;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding .ConfigureAwait(false) at the task that hangs? there are many articles talking about this problem with switch contexting that await hangs.

Comment: Another note, if you find your self using ConfigureAwait too much and it makes your code ugly, you can always do it on the assembly level using this nice project: https://github.com/distantcam/ConfigureAwait

Comment: Could you please post the code of `GetStaticChampionByIdAsync`?

Comment: I added it in approach 2, the one with the foreach loop. It does still not work. When adding it to the first approach with the linq select, I can't await it anymore and the compiler marks the Task.WhenAll...

Comment: I'd love to see the implementation of `ApiClientProvider`. Also, how is the method containing the provided code called? You're not using .Wait() / .Result anywhere do you?

Comment: @MartinZikmund That code comes not from me. It from https://github.com/aj-r/RiotNet

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` is a hack and should not be used to solve deadlocks because all async calls anywhere in the chain must also do so. It is easy to break during future maintenance.

Comment: Could you also please post the code that calls the code snippet you have posted?

Comment: @Crowcoder It's not a hack. It is best practice to use it when you are sure that the context is not needed.

Comment: @selmaohneh that is untrue. Best practice is to use synchronous API's if you cannot go async "all the way down". Have you read [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) ? You can also observe for yourself how [ConfigureAwait doesn't always save you](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/12/04/configureawait-sometimes-saves-the-day-everytime/)

Comment: @PeterBons No, not that I'm aware of. :) And i added the desired code.

Comment: @GiladReich to me, that looks like a dangerous thing to do. The reason the default is `ConfigureAwait(true)` is because it is better to err on the side of caution - some code is "context aware" and cannot resume on a different synchronization context (HttpContext as an example). If you blanket apply this you can have problems that may be very hard to diagnose. Plus, any assemblies you are referencing have to be careful to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` or you still can have a continuation problem.

Comment: What makes you think that this actually deadlocks? Did you try debugging the code to see if the asnychronous processes run properly? Did you try running it with just one “freeToPlayChampion”? Did you try fetching the data one after another instead of having the async calls run in parallel?